# Do I need to install ALL the service packs for visual studio or just the latest?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have just installed Visual Studio 2013. I am wondering do I need to install ALL the service packs for visual studio or just the latest?

For example I have installed CTP5 and when I go to 'about' then it says CTP5 is it safe to assume that all the other service packs up to 5 have been installed?

[image]

Comment: Just the latest. It includes the changes from all the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the official updates are designed to be *cumulative* such as the last official [update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx) where it specifically says:

> This update is the latest in a cumulative series of feature additions
> and bug fixes for Visual Studio 2013.".

But since this is a [CTP (communitiy tehcnology preview) update 5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45508) (U5 has not officially been released and not meant for production machines):

> PLEASE NOTE: This Community Technology Preview has not been subject to final validation and is not meant to be run on production workstations or servers.
>
> For the Visual Studio update package: The recommended approach for
> upgrading Visual Studio on test workstations is installing the latest
> Visual Studio Update CTP on top of an RTM release or a previous CTP
> build of that Update. Visual Studio CTPs can be upgraded to a
> different build.

With that wording `on top of an RTM release` it implies that one does not have to install the previous updates; hence this is intended to be a rollup cumulative release as well.

Comment: Sorry can I just confirm that the meaning of the word 'cumulative' in this context means that update 4 contains 1-3?

Comment: @Exitos yes, it contains updates 1-4 and this will be update 5 when officially released.

Comment: @Exitos To be clear, each update contains all the previous; hence cumulative.